# What kind of device in this circuit

Tags: inductor

It's a power entry part of a DAQ card, the bottom right is a DC jack. The power flow maybe:

Power DC jack -> ferrite bead -> cap -> common mode inductor -> cap -> ?

I guess the bigger black one may be a common mode inductor too. But I've never saw such a bigger one in this kind of package, and it seems it's full shielded, can't see the coils from side.

May anyone give some clues?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you use GIMP or Photoshop or another program to assign ad hoc part ID's to each part you have a question about. A DVM and a LCR meter would go a long way toward solving what these parts are. Sure, some are obvious, but to estimate current flow from here to there without ref numbers is well, just guessing. We are not fond of guessing as we don't want to mislead the OP asking the questions.

Comment: It would also help if you could zoom out just a bit so we can see more parts.

Comment: My money is on a bridge rectifier, poke around with a meter in diode mode and see what you get.

Comment: @Sparky256 I've no electron microscope by hand, this is best what I can take using my cell phone.

Comment: Diverger, Sparky said zoom *out*, not in. We'd like to see more of what is on the board. Electron microscopes are for zooming in very close, which would not help.

Comment: I agree it looks like a common mode choke also. You could try measuring the DCR, I guess.

Comment: Gee...2 rectangle SMD devices with 4 pins and a cap at each end. Plug must be power, with series resistors? One is a bridge rectifier, the other bulky one could be a CM choke. This is like the chicken and egg thing... Large empty pads are confusing.

Comment: Guessing....Solid state relay, power regulator chip, ceramic crystal filter,bridge rectifier . God knows...

Comment: A partially reverse engineered schematic would be useful. It seems to have a cap across its pins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the black doodads appear to be common-mode chokes. Really looks like ferrite rather than a molded semiconductor package. Test with a small magnet to confirm. Ferrite should be strongly attracted, otherwise it would just be the leadframe which isn't much metal.

So a bunch of filtering to keep hash from the switchmode power supply from getting out the power port (that black thing on the lower right is a barrel jack typically used for power).

There might be an option for a larger CM choke rather than the tiny one, judging by those unused pads.

Edit: Here's what I see. Mostly 100% sure, C5 is a bit iffy. The leftmost chip is probably a SMPS chip- looks like a diode below it, and probably an inductor out of shot above it. L1 and L2 are ferrite beads.

[image: schematic]

Comment: CM chokes are critical to good EMI egress results by raising the CM impedance but keeping DM impedance low which is filtered by the discrete LCL chips after jack.  Low egress reduces the mutual coupling to long sensor cables with higher impedance. Critical for high CMRR that cannot be reduces with an INA of 120dB CMRR if the cable have 1% coupling or. CMRR of 40dB

Comment: Now, I suspect it's maybe a bigger CMC covered by a self made metal cover. Because apparently there is plenty space for some marking on it, but it has nothing on the shell.